# Change color of dojo list text box in a xpages

Tags: list, text, dojo, xpages, box

I would like to know if there is how to change the color of a specific item in the dojo list text box component on an xpages. The intention is to emphasize the value that represents the next queue attendant, which in this case will be represented by the values ​​in the dojo list text box.

Comment: Can you post what you have you tried?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. For now I'm just researching solution alternatives.

Comment: Ok cool. I haven't seen a dijit list text box. Dojo has text box so what exactly you mean by dojo list text box ? Sorry if I have missed something here.

Comment: Dojo list text box is a component of xpages, as shown below

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/extlib_controlref_djextlisttextbox.html

Answer (score 0):

It's an XPages component, so there are two options.

1. Output custom HTML to the browser depending on the value, by creating a custom renderer on the server side.
2. Accept the standard HTML output by XPages and then use standard JavaScript approaches (jQuery if you have Bootstrap, `dojo.behavior` if OneUI) to post-process the DOM programmatically and manipulate styling.